# How to query partitions that you get from using window functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table that has the following structure

```
------------------------------------
|Company_ID| Company_Name| Join_Key|
------------------------------------
|     1    | ACompany    | AC      |
|     2    | BCompany    | BC      |
```

While this table doesn't have many column, there are somewhere around 4 million rows.

I want to calculate some string distance calculations on these company names. I have the following query

```
select a.Company_Name as Name1,
       b.Company_Name as Name2,
       Fuzzy_Match(a.Company_Name, b.Company_Name, 'JaccardDistance') as Jaccard --this is a custom function
from [Companies] a, [Companies] b
```

While something like this would work on a smaller database, since my database is so large, there is no way for me to be able to get through all of the combinations in a reasonable amount of time. So I thought about partitioning the database with a window function.

```
select Company_Name,
       ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Join_Key order by Join_Key asc) as row_num
       Join_Key
from [Companies]
```

This gives me a list of the companies numbered and partitioned by their join_key, but the thing that I'm not sure of is how to do both things.

*How can I perform a cross join and calculate the string similarity measures for each partition so that I'm only comparing companies that both have 'AC' as their join key?*

Comment: If you have 4,000,000 rows then the cross join produces 16,000,000,000,000 rows.  Does the `fuzz_match()` call in the `select` really filter these results?

Comment: Use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `CROSS JOIN`?  Such as `FROM [Companies] a INNER JOIN [Companies] b ON a.Join_Key = b.Join_Key`?  Not sure what you're trying to do with the analytical functions, but I can't seen them being necessary / relevant, from what I understand of your post.

Comment: That scalar function is likely going to hinder performance here too...but not as much as the cross join.

Comment: One thought is to also use NGrams method so split the company name into letters (tokens) and only compare those records that share more than x+# of letters (3+).  That way you are not doing an entire cross join.  And as others have said scalar performance will be poor, you could look at a clr table valued function which should net better performance, and before others go crazy I have tried and I do get better performance with CLR for larger string manipulations but of course that needs to be optimized correctly but threading can be used...

Comment: @GordonLinoff No it does not do any filtering. It just calculates the Jaccard Distance between  two strings.

Comment: @MatBailie I need to calculate string similarity distances between different company names. The custom function calculates different distance measures.

Comment: @j.jerrod.taylor - Yeah...  So using an the `INNER JOIN` I mentioned will ensure that you only compare companies that have the same `Join_Key`.

Comment: @MatBailie I made the change that you suggested but I'm thinking it will still take way to long for the entire query to complete? Is there anyway to run the queries for the different join_keys in parallel? I have about 1,300 different join keys, some of them are way bigger then others. If I could run this query on all of the join_keys at the same time it.

Comment: If I had this problem, I would use n-grams in a separate table to match company names.